# Reverse Insertion sort

Tags: code-golf, array

## Objective

Generate the original scrambled list, from the movements that an [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) would do to sort it.
The original list will have all numbers from `0` to `N-1`(inclusive) where `N` is the size of the input.

## Input

A list containing the necessary moves to sort the list. Each value represents the amount of slots displaced by the original (scrambled) number to be in his right position , keep in mind that this process is from the left to the right.
The value at (0-indexed) position `i` in the input list will be between `0` and `i` inclusive.
You don't need to handle invalid inputs, any behaviour is acceptable in this case (crash, infinite loop, etc).

## Output

The scrambled list

#### Step-by-step to generate the moves

```
Scrambled List | Moves to sort
[4,0,2,1,3,5]  | [0, , , , , ] #4 stay in place
[4,0,2,1,3,5]  | [0,1, , , , ] #0 is moved 1 slot to the left
[0,4,2,1,3,5]  | [0,1,1, , , ] #2 is moved 1 slot
[0,2,4,1,3,5]  | [0,1,1,2, , ] #1 is moved 2 slot
[0,1,2,4,3,5]  | [0,1,1,2,1, ] #3 is moved 1 slot
[0,1,2,3,4,5]  | [0,1,1,2,1,0] #5 is in the right place already
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

So, for the input `[0,1,1,2,1,0]` your program need to output `[4,0,2,1,3,5]`.
Keep in mind that the movements aren't to the position in the (final) sorted list, but in the sorted segment(the bolded section)

## Test Cases

```
[0,0,0] -> [0,1,2]
[0,1,0,1] -> [1,0,3,2]
[0,0,0,0,0,5] -> [1,2,3,4,5,0]
[0,1,2,3] -> [3,2,1,0]
[0,1,1,1] -> [3,0,1,2]
[0,1,1,2,1,0] -> [4,0,2,1,3,5]
```

## Winning

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.

Comment: May the program also take the length of the list as input?

Comment: @mbomb007 nope.

Comment: Can we use (n-1) steps instead? The first one is unnecessary, since it's always zero.

Comment: @GB sure, as long the output is right, you can use any algorithm

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
L!_UÆ¡$œ?J’U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@@jGB96uO3QQpWjk@29HjXMDP1/uP1R05r//6OjDXSAMFYHSBsCWYZgFgyaQsWNdIyhLEOoCkOwKFBHbCwA)

### Explanation

We can basically see the two lists (the input and the output) as encoding an integer; the input encodes an integer in factorial base, and the output encodes an integer as a permutation. Luckily, Jelly has builtins that are already very close to both of these encodings, so it's simply a matter of writing small pieces of code to convert to an integer, then back to the other encoding.

```
L!_UÆ¡$œ?J’U
   U           Reverse {the input}
    Æ¡         and convert from base factorial to integer;
  _   $        subtract that from
L!             the factorial of the length of {the input};
       œ?      then take the nth permutation of
         J     [1,2,...,l], where l is the length of {the input},
          ’    subtract 1 from every elevent,
           U   and reverse it
```

In the case of base factorial, we can observe that the first element of the list must be 0, the second can be 0 or 1, the third must be 0/1/2, and so on. Thus, we have to reverse the input in order to get its elements into the normal writing order for base conversion.

Additionally, for the relative orders of the factorial conversion and the permutation conversion to match up with the operation that insertion sort uses, we need to make two adjustments: reversing the sequence of the permutations, and reversing the order of the output list. Reversing the output list is easy enough, needing only a `U` at the end of the program. To reverse the sequence of permutations, we subtract from the factorial of the input length (this works because the base factorial produces a number in the range 0 to (length!-1), whereas the permutations are numbered by Jelly from 1 to length!, producing an implicit off-by-one that cancels out the off-by-one that you normally get when subtracting a permutation index from a factorial).

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes, in collaboration with @JonathanAllan

```
UÆ¡Nœ?J’U
```

This version of the program is very similar, but uses a different method of reversing the sequence of permutations; simply negating the input with `N` is enough to make `œ?` treat the order in reverse. Apart from that, it works identically to the previous program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x96uO3QQr@jk@29HjXMDP1/uP1R05r//6OjDXSAMFYHSBsCWYZgFgyaQsWNdIyhLEOoCkOwKFBHbCwA)

Comment: O_O What sorcery *is* this?

Comment: Oh nice - I knew my `Æ¡` and `œ?` atoms would work for this (I had already started trying to use them for this challenge earlier - I was so close, just needed the `L!` in there).

Comment: Excellent code!

Comment: In fact, you can do it in **9** bytes with `UÆ¡Nœ?L’U` because I implemented `œ?` (and similar) to act modularly  (as if they were using Jelly lists). The `N` just indexes in with the negative value. Note: I changed `J` to `L` - this is just because given a number it makes a range under-the-hood anyway).

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 92 bytes

```
Permute[Range[l=Length@#]-1,(c=Cycles@{#}&)@{}©##&@@c[i-0~Range~#[[i]]]~Table~{i,l,1,-1}]&
```

Pure function taking a list of nonnegative integers as input and returning a list of nonnegative integers. The above code contains a `©`, which is incorrect: it's a placeholder for the 3-byte symbol U+F3DE, which Mathematica represents by a circle with a dot in it, and which represents composition of permutations.

`c=Cycles@{#}&` defines a function that converts a list of integers into a `Cycles` object representing a permutation; for example, `c[{3,4}]` is the transposition swapping elements 3 and 4 of a list. `c[i-0~Range~#[[i]]]~Table~{i,l,1,-1}]` takes the input list and generates the permutations necessary to undo the insertion sort. Then `c@{}©##&@@` composes all of these permutations together, starting with the identity permutation `c@{}`. Finally, `Permute[Range[l=Length@#]-1,...]` applies this permutation to the 0-indexed list of appropriate length.

Comment: What no built-in?! Surely...

Comment: `@{#}&)@{}©##&@@` looks scary.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <strike>79</strike> 68 bytes

Thanks to Krazor for saving 10 bytes

Thanks to TuukkaX for saving 1 byte

```py
a=input();b=range(len(a));print[b.pop(j-a[j])for j in b[::-1]][::-1]
```

Works by generating the moves in reverse

Comment: Make that **66**! How about: `a=input();b=range(len(a));print[b.pop(j-a[j]) for j in b[::-1]][::-1]`. List comprehensions ftw!

Comment: @Krazor You have a space that could be removed before `for`, so make that **65** I guess :D

Comment: @Krazor Turns out the list comprehension didn't quite work, but I liked the idea of using b[::-1] !

Comment: No way? I commented with mobile, maybe I mistyped something. Which part does not work? For me, it interpreted correctly and fulfilled all test cases.

Comment: @Krazor Oh whoops, no you're right. I'm the one who mistyped it while testing.

Comment: That's cool, seems like I miscounted my letters? Sorry about that. Also, how come I didn't receive any rep for the upvotes on my comment? Do things work differently over here?

Comment: @Krazor No reputation is gained from upvotes on comments.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>69</s> <s>65</s> 63 bytes

```
a=>a.reverse(b=[...a.keys()]).map(o=>+b.splice(~o,1)).reverse()
```

Annoyingly both input and output are in the wrong order. Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Arnauld. Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions.

Comment: I was still trying to find a better way but you were much faster. Nice one!

Comment: You don't need `i`, do you?

Comment: @Arnauld Apparently not. I started by trying to understand the Python answer, and I've only just noticed that it doesn't actually use `i`...

Comment: Easy -2: `o=>+b.splice(~o,1)`

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> 71 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to ETHproductions*

```js
m=>(a=m.map((_,i)=>j=i)).map(_=>a.splice(j,0,+a.splice(j-m[j--],1)))&&a
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

m=>(a=m.map((_,i)=>j=i)).map(_=>a.splice(j,0,+a.splice(j-m[j--],1)))&&a

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([0,0,0])));       // -> [0,1,2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([0,1,0,1])));     // -> [1,0,3,2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([0,0,0,0,0,5]))); // -> [1,2,3,4,5,0]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([0,1,2,3])));     // -> [3,2,1,0]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([0,1,1,1])));     // -> [3,0,1,2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([0,1,1,2,1,0]))); // -> [4,0,2,1,3,5]
```

Comment: Nice way of getting the length and the range at the same time. I was gonna suggest `a=m.map(_=>j++,j=0)`, but that's the same length and I'm sure you've already tried it.

Comment: @ETHproductions You're right: I've tried it as well. :-) (It may be worth noting that this is not equivalent: this would set `j` to `a.length` rather than `a.length-1` and would require `a.splice(--j,0,a.splice(j-m[j],1)[0])`)

Comment: Heh, I thought of that too, but I didn't think it was worth mentioning because it's the same length

Comment: Easy -2: `+a.splice(j-m[j--],1)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 85 bytes

```hs
f x|n<-length x-1=reverse x#[n,n-1..0]
(n:r)#l=r#(take n l++drop(n+1)l)++[l!!n]
x#l=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#DcpBCsMgEEDRfU4xwS6UiUG7LPUk4iKQSRtqp2EqxUXvbuTzdr9tUP98t5n4UZ5QrQ9CP5IvQVWRJ7Z@nl0aNN/EqBxE6bK8CBgy4iqfQzN6kw1izOPIaah9qu297AwBDtm5wAU2iG7yvWvnUjsB) Example usage: `f [0,1,1,2,1,0]` yields `[4,0,2,1,3,5]`.

`f x` calls the function `#` with list `x` reversed and a list `[length x - 1, length x - 2, ... , 0]`. `(n:r)#l` performs the reverse insertion sort by recursively taking the `n`th element out of `l`, where `l!!n` yields the `n`th element and `take n l++drop(n+1)l` yields the list `l` with the `n`th element removed.

Comment: Haskell, so beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

## perl, 61 bytes

```
@o=@p=0..@ARGV-1;splice@o,$_,0,splice@o,$_-pop,1for reverse@p
```

Output ends up in array @o. Example with input array as command line arguments:

```
perl -le'@o=@p=0..@ARGV-1;splice@o,$_,0,splice@o,$_-pop,1for reverse@p;print@o' 0 1 1 2 1 0
402135
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 49 bytes

```
->l{(w=l.size).times{l.insert(l.shift+w-=1,w)};l}
```

Performs the "reverse insertion" in place inside the list, starting with the largest number.